# SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install openstack and ovsVapp in my server. Everything goes well during initial stage. Later got an error in n-cpu saying SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.

And one more error saying in n-cpu

/usr/local/bin/nova-compute --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf

No handlers could be found for logger "oslo_config.cfg"

Answer (score -2):

Edit the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_vmware/service.py`
at line 141.

comment out the line saying 
`self.verify = cacert if cacert else not insecure`
and add one extra line 
`self.verify = False`
i.e

```
#self.verify = cacert if cacert else not insecure
self.verify = False
```

and re run the n-cpu again.

Or execute `./unstack.sh` and `./stack.sh` for fresh setup